# How can I detect that there is not enough space for div block?

Tags: javascript, cursor

I want to display div near the cursor in the "right-bottom" direction. But when the user moves cursor close to the right bottom corner div block should be mirrored and displayed in the "left-top" direction.

How can I detect that the cursor is too close to the right / bottom side and div block will be displayed only with scrolls?

Comment: Look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx